# MVC - After dynamic Partial Load, SubModel doesn't update for save

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a Model   which is in a PartialView  _Model.cshtml and it has a SubModel which has a partial view _SubModel.cshtml.

When you switch an item in a drop down list, i'm sending an Ajax call to reload the SubModel with appropriate default data.  The ajax call returns a valid sub model, and that part all works.  The page looks correct, has the correct data, and you can edit it etc.  When you Save ( located on the BaseModel ) the Model is available in the Postback but none of the SubModel information is available.

Example

```
public class SubModel { 
   public int Id {get;set;}
}
public class Model { 
   public string ModelType {get;set;}
   public SubModel Details {get;set;}
}
```

View Example

```
@Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m=> m.ModelType).BindTo( Model.AvailableModelTypes)

<div id="subModelPartial">
   @Html.PartialFor(m => m.Details, "~/Features/_SubModel.cshtml")
</div>

/// More page stuff....
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#@(Html.IdFor(m=> m.ModelType))').change(function(){
            var url = "@Url.Action("GetSubModel", "Model")"; 
            var query { ... }; // query data.
            $('#subModelPartial').load(url, query);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller Example

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("GetSubModel")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetSubModel( Query query ) 
{
   var subModel = await GetSubModel(query); 
   return PartialView("_SubModel.cshtml", subModel ?? new SubModel()); 
}
```

When I save the Model is fully populated, but the Details object everything is defaulted, even though it shows populated on the page.

What am i Missing?  I want to be able to update the model on the page and have it save with everything else?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like your problem is in saving data? Could you update your question with details of how you save data? ex is it jquery or form post, and does `_SubModel.cshtml` define the names of its properties appropriately to be bound by the MVC model binder

Comment: You are creating a partial for `SubModel` which will have inputs with `name="Id"`, but to bind to `Model`, it needs to be `name="Details.Id"` (you partial needs to be based on `@model Model` and the inputs need to be generated using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Details.Id)` to generate the correct name attributes for binding (or you need to pass the `HtmlFieldPrefix` to the partial)